# Make AutoComplPop allow hyphen as a word charcter

Tags: vim, autocomplete

This screenshot explains the problem I'm having:

[image]

I would like `address-font` rather than `address` to appear in the AutoComplPop dropdown, as hyphenated class names are common in idiomatic css.  But by default they are considered the end of a word.

How can I configure ACP so that a hyphen is treated just like any other letter and the full class names appear as options for autocompletion?

Comment: Most likely `set iskeyword+=-`

Comment: Thank you!  If you want to create that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting `iskeyword` controls what characters vim uses to determine word characters. `-` is not normally considered part of a word. To add it use

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

Take a look at `:h 'iskeyword'`