# How to use vim's "ctrl+]" to find function defined with '-'

Tags: vim, makefile, ctags

Hi~I'm new here and I get a problem with vim.

I got makefiles and there were functions defined with **'-'** such as **"stub-addon-jar"**.

Then I used ctags generating tags file which actually got those functions's definition.

After that I opened a makefile with vim ,set the tag variable, tested **"ctrl+]"** with a normal variable and it worked normally.

Then I put cursor on where function **"stub-addon-jar"** was called and stroke **"ctrl+]"**. But vim showed "tag not found: addon".

It seems vim did't get the whole **"stub-addon-jar"** but just **"addon"** as tag's input.

How could I fix this problem? Is it because of the method vim use to split words?

Comment: Exactly the same answer as this question I answered earlier today, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049838/make-autocomplpop-allow-hyphen-as-a-word-charcter

Comment: @FDinoff You answer is great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As FDinoff mentioned in his comment, the correct solution is to change vim's definition of a word to include the `-` character.

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

After setting this, your tag jump should work correctly.

Here is another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225266/customising-word-separators-in-vi) discussing the addition and removal of characters to the definition of a word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex search instead of the default whole word search:

```
:tag /addon<CR>
nnoremap <C-]> :tag /<c-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult one.  I've tried several things but it does the same to me when I name a function like that.  The closest I could get was to place the cursor on the function and press either `gd` (to search for local definition) or `gD` to search outside the current file.

Note, gd and gD (go to definition) are built-in vim commands.

One of my favorite plug-ins is [taglist.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273).  It doesn't go to definition by clicking on the calling point.  It will show you a list of all functions in a file and let you transport to any of them by clicking on them.  It's having no problems with those names.

Comment: In fact, I'v tried gD and taglist. My situation now is that a makefile  includes aother one in a subdir. The later calls functions defined in the former. Taglist just shows the variable and functions in the local file. And gD works not as expected when the function's name consists of some common words. BUT still thank you for your answer!